# Cannot connect to localhost when fiddler is opened

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I have configured a localhost with iis. I can connect to the local environment when fiddler is not opened. However, when I open fiddler, my localhost is suddenly not accessible.

The reason I ask this question is because I am having a problem getting request from my localhost with HttpResponseMessage. HttpClient.GetAsync‌ throws an I/O exception from my localhost, but it works well for an online secure site.

Please let me know if you guys have any ideas.
Thanks!

Comment: I used to see this problem in Fiddler version 2x but Fiddler version 4x and above doesn't have this problem. Instead of localhost try to access your system using IP, it works.

Comment: The Fiddler version is v4.6.2.26757

Answer (score 1):

Might possibly be because fiddler is set to bypass the loopback address which is typically localhost by default.
Check the connection Settings under tools, fiddler Options.

Note the Bypass Fiddler for URLs that start with settings.
Try removing the loopback and see if it helps.

[image: Fiddler Connection Settings]

Comment: I have tried to remove <-loopback> manually, but it is still there when I restart fiddler